# What C/C++ libraries exist to transform vectors between map projections

Tags: coordinate-system, library, vector

Has anybody written a C/C++ library (preferably one that is aware of Proj.4 definition strings) that has a set of routines to convert vector quantities (e.g., wind speed and direction) between map coordinate systems? That is, routines to do calculations described in something like:

http://www.dtcenter.org/met/users/docs/write_ups/velocity.pdf

I have found the [EMAPF routines](http://www.arl.noaa.gov/HYSPLIT_emapfcuse.php), but was wondering whether there was anything Proj.4 aware.

Gordon